# Unable to enable Jetty compression while using Solr 4.4

Tags: exception, solr, jetty, gzip

I am trying to run Solr 4.4.0 using the Jetty distribution that comes along with it. I wish to enable GZip compression on Jetty in order to reduce network traffic. I am trying to run the default "example" that is provided in the distribution. I edited the example/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml file to add the following lines under :

```
<filter>
<filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>mimeTypes</param-name>
  <param-value>text/html,text/plain,text/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/css,application/javascript,image/svg+xml</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

However, during startup, I am getting the following exception:

```
931  [main] WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Holder  – 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:421)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:383)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:100)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:79)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:91)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:719)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1252)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:39)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:494)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:56)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:337)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:121)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:555)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1259)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1182)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:615)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
933  [main] WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle  – FAILED    GzipFilter: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:104)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:91)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:719)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1252)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:39)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:494)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:56)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:337)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:121)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:555)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1259)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1182)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:615)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
934  [main] WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext  – Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/solr,file:/home/diptesh/solr-4.4.0/solr/example/solr-webapp/webapp/},/home/diptesh/solr-4.4.0/solr/example/webapps/solr.war
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:104)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:91)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:719)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1252)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:39)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:494)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:56)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:337)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:121)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:555)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1259)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1182)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:615)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
```

Solr server is starting up and I am also able to query Solr normally. But the results are not getting gzipped. Can someone tell me what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to add the jetty-servlets artifact to the startup configuration for solr.  I don't know how Solr starts up but if they use the start.ini file then you should be able to add something like:

OPTIONS=jetty-servlets

Comment: Solr with jetty does use a start.config file which is embedded inside start.jar. Apparently the distribution I was using was missing the jetty-servlets-<versionId>.jar file. Downloading the file and copying it into ${jetty.home}/lib solved the problem.

Comment: yeah, custom solr distro...not a lot we can do about that